# python numpy load torch model .t7 file

Tags: python, numpy, torch

I got a torch7 model, and I need to load the model in python using numpy,I tried to load the model with

```
parameters = np.load("model")
```

but I got the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "loadTorchModel.py", line 7, in <module>
params = np.load('Mnist_ascii')
File "/home/mht/.local/lib/python2.7/sitepackages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 443, in load
"Failed to interpret file %s as a pickle" % repr(file))
IOError: Failed to interpret file 'Mnist_ascii' as a pickle
```

Is there anyway I can load a .t7 model in python and convert it to numpy array?

Comment: How did you generate the model?  'np.load' loads files containing numpy arrays, the error message suggests that the file doesn't contain a numpy array.

Comment: @user2699 thanks for your help! I generate the model.t7 file by torch7 code : torch.save("model.t7",model,"ascii"),  and I think may be it can't be done directly, here is my solution for now , read .t7 file in python with the help of 
 https://github.com/bshillingford/python-torchfile. and then do more precess to convert.